# Why do I need to assign the Canvas's font to change font size in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-2009

I've got an subclass of TPanel which I love so very very much and much to my chagrin, the font never seems to take when doing this:

```
font.size := AFontsize;
font.style := AFontStyle;
font.color := AFontColor;
```

but it does change when I do this:

```
Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
```

I didn't have to do that in Delphi 7, but I seem to have to do it in 2009. What's the deal?

Comment: Perhaps `ParentFont:= true`?, first set ParentFont:= false, then try again.

Comment: @Johan, changing the font automatically sets parentfont to false (try it in the OI).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you paint text in the panel using its canvas, you must set the canvas font.

Some components and/or some Delphi versions can, either intentionally or as a side effect of a prior painting task, set `Canvas.Font`, but you shouldn't rely on it.

So it's recommended to do `Canvas.Font := Font;` prior to begin painting text.

The same applies to `Canvas.Brush` and `Canvas.Pen`.

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

procedure TMyPanel.Paint;
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  r := ClientRect;

  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(r); // fill the background

  Canvas.Font := Font;
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, 'Sample Text', -1, r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOPREFIX);
end;
```

Comment: Is `Canvas.Font := Font;` really a recommended way? Should it not rather be `Canvas.Font.Assign(Font)`?

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried this and setting `Canvas.Font.assign(Font)` caused a redraw on the thing I was drawing (hence, a lot of flickering) I must have done it the other way around by accident.

Comment: @AndriyM: VCL usually uses `Canvas.Font := Font`. Therefore it is the same as using `Assign`, as the set procedure of the `Font` property itself does an `Assign`.